# insert and edit with checkbox coding

Tags: php

I am a newible on php and I am following a video to learn inserting data in website to database, but I face a huge problem.

As I am going to from many groups from many members, i create some checkboxs for member to register.
I followed this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0HiIUclMv1k),but have error.

```
<?php
//$_SESSION['name'];
session_start();
echo "student";
?>

<form action="" method="POST">    
<input type="checkbox" name="group[]" value="group1">group1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="group[]" value="group2">group2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="group[]" value="group3">group3<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="group[]" value="group4">group4<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="group[]" value="group5">group5<br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">   
</form>

<?php

    if  (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        //print_r($_POST);
    echo implode(',', $POST['group']);
}
?>

</h1>
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
```

All things that I wanna do was followed for these coding but still have error

> Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\fyp\student.php on line 37

```
echo implode(',', $POST['group']);
```

what was wrong with it, thank you for any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're forgetting the underscore before the POST. Here is that line fixed:

```
echo implode(',', $_POST['group']);
```

There are a few other simple issues that might cause some trouble later on. First, in terms of syntax, you should close your HTML input tags (like below):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="group[]" value="group1" />group1<br>
...
```

Next, you will get this same error when no checkboxes are selected as the variable `$_POST['group']` has not been defined yet. You can use the PHP `empty()` function to test this variable (http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) before you call the `implode()`.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `$_` before `POST` .

Instead of this

```
echo implode(',', $POST['group']);
```

use this

```
echo implode(',', $_POST['group']);
```